# UIImage is returning null

Tags: iphone, null, uiimage, xcode6

I created app that perfectly works on xcode 5, but it not show images in xcode 6, in iphone 6 simulator.
This code is returning null.

**code:**

```
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Img1@2x.png"];
```

Comment: Try `UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Img1"]; //`

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue once, the cause of this issue was that I am not taking care of image name by assigning it to **UIImageView**, make sure that you are assigning **UIImageView** the exact name of the image as it is in the main bundle.

The simulator can read the image name if there is any case-sensitive issue or some extension issue like i.e. .png , .jpg, but device never reads the image name if there are issues in the naming conventions, device always treat the image name as exact.